# How do I log text and a variable in the same line in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I am relativly new to coding with Python.

I recently set up a gps logging device with a raspberry pi and I want to make my log file look cleaner.

My current code for logging is:

```
logging.info('Altitude:')
logging.info(gpsd.fix.altitude)
```

It logs:

```
INFO:root:Altitude:
INFO:root:80
```

What I want to see in the log is:

```
Altitude: 80
```

I tried to do this with my limited knowledge with python, but it only resulted in failure.

Thanks!
Also, any other tips for cleaning up the log file?

Comment: Use [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format)

Comment: What did you try? What error did you get when you tried it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
logging.info('Altitude:%s' % gpsd.fix.altitude)
```

Comment: The `%s` will stringify anything you pass it, so calling `str` is redundant.

Answer (score 8):

In Python >=3.6 you can do this :

```
logging.info(f"Altitude: {gpsd.fix.altitude}")
```

By adding the "f" at the beginning of the string the value between brackets will be interpreted as a variable and will be replaced by its value.

Answer (score 5):

If altitude is a decimal then

```
logging.info('Altitude: %d' % gpsd.fix.altitude)
```

will do it, there are several other ways to achieve the same thing though as I'm sure others can present!

Comment: @user2799617 That's a ridiculous reason.

Answer (score 4):

```
logging.info('{}:{}'.format("Altitude", gpsd.fix.altitude)
```

You can use `format` method. Have a look at the [examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to understand `format` better.

**Example:**

```
print '{}:{}'.format("Altitude", 80)
```

**Output**

```
Altitude:80
```